# fscanf reads twice a line

Tags: c

I'm using fscanf in a text file like this:

```
T 1 1000
T 2 700
N 3 450
Y 4 200
```

I'm trying to count the lines to use a malloc and to do that I use:

```
Prize temp;
int count =0;
while ((fscanf(fa,"%c %d %f", &temp.A, &temp.B, &temp.C))!= EOF)
count ++;
```

where Prize is a struct:

```
typedef struct {
  char A;
  int B;
  float C;
} Prize;
```

So, after reading the lines the program prints me this:

```
 A: T B: 1 C: 1000.0000
 A:   B: 0 C: 0.0000
 A: T B: 2 C: 700.0000
 A:   B: 0 C: 0.0000
 A: N B: 3 C: 450.0000
 A:   B: 0 C: 0.0000
 A: Y B: 4 C: 200.0000
```

Using the debugger I noticed that `fscanf` gets (for example while reading the first line):

A = 84 'T', B=1, C=1000

and instead of reading the second line it reads another first line, but like this:

A = 10'\n', B=1, C=1000

and continues doing this for each line but the last.

I controlled the file and it doesn't have extra spaces or lines.

Any suggestions to solve the problem?

Comment: `fscanf(fa, " %c%d%f", ...)`

Comment: `fscanf(fa,"%c %d %f", &temp.A, &temp.B, &temp.C))` --> `fscanf(fa," %c %d %f", &temp.A, &temp.B, &temp.C))`

Comment: Also , `!=EOF` is not a complete solution, it must be `==3`, also.

Comment: "...it doesn't have excess spaces or lines" - might want to consider what causes the start of new lines, and why checking specifically for a return result of `3` with each read would probably have found this sooner. [maybe **read this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240789/scanf-leaves-the-new-line-char-in-buffer).

Comment: @sagivd that may unwantedly fail the last line.

Comment: Do you actually need to verify the format of the lines that you are counting?  It is probably sufficient to count the number of newlines in the file, and for that `scanf` is the wrong tool.  (It is probably sufficient to not bother counting the lines and process the data on the first pass, but that is a different issue.)

Comment: Not an _exact_ dupe, but [may be helpful](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29658685/2173917)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your file contains newlines. So the sequence of characters in the file is really as following:

```
T 1 1000\nT 2 700\n...
```

The first fscanf reads `'T'`, `1`, and `1000`.  It stops at the `'\n'` character.

The seconds fscanf reads the `'\n'` character to `temp.A`. Now it is at the second 'T' character. Therefore, it is unable to read `temp.B` and `temp.C`

The third fscanf reads `'T'`, `2`, and `700`, but stops at `'\n'` again.

You should skip all whitespace characters before reading `temp.A`, which is done by the space in the format string:

```
...fscanf(fa," %c %d %f", &temp.A, &temp.B, &temp.C)...
```

Answer (score 0):

The `%c` format of the reading would not ignore any `space` or `\n` character, even which it is unseen. However `%s %d %c` will. It is likely the better way to avoid the inconsistency if replace `%c` by `%s`(and single character to be a string).

```
char str[maxn];
fscanf(fa, "%s%d%f", str, &temp.B, &temp.C);
temp.A = str[0];
```