# The practical difference of %c vs %s

Tags: c, arrays, char, scanf, format-specifiers

I'm required to do a seafood menu as an assignment in my college. I will provide the relevant code here:

```
 int main ()
{
int a,d;
float c ;
char b,s,S,m,M,l,L;

printf ("\n\t\t\t\tSeafood Menu\n");
printf ("----------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
printf ("\t\t\t\t\t\t      Dish Size\n");
printf ("Item Number\t Seafood Dish\t      Small\t       Medium      Large\t\n");
printf ("----------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
printf ("\t 1\t Fried   \t20.00 \t\t 40.00 \t\t 55.00\n");
    //Continue with a bunch of menu here

    printf ("   Enter item number            :");
    scanf ("%d",&a);
    printf ("   Enter dish size (S/M/L) :");
    scanf ("%s",&b);


        if ((a==1)&&((b=='s')||(b=='S')))
        {c=20.00;}
        //continue with a bunch of condition to choose the price per dish stated in the menu


    printf ("   Enter dish quantity     :");
    scanf ("%d",&d);
    printf ("   Price per dish size     :RM%.2f\n\n\n",c);


return 0;    
}
```

When I tried to change the format identifier in this to %c, it just stopped accepting input for that particular scanf.

```
printf ("Enter dish size (S/M/L):");
scanf ("%s",b);
```

I would like to attach images but it seems that I am not allowed to do so 'll leave two links:

[Normal, using %s:](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5ZapshmNPs2OFFoUlVaSzI4Vk0) and [abnormal, using %c](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5ZapshmNPs2el9NSDBUTTJvbEk)

I'm curious about why it doesn't work when I use `%c` while `%s` works? As all I enter there is just character. Please enlighten me.

Comment: Both variants invoke undefined behaviour. Please read the documentation of `scanf` and about the difference of a character and an _array of characters_, resp. a C string.

Comment: The behavior of `%c` and `%s` should be clearly spelled out in your handy C reference manual.  If you don't have a handy C reference manual, I recommend Harbison & Steele's [C: A Reference Manual](http://careferencemanual.com).  `%c` reads a *single* character from the input stream and stores it to a single `char` object.  `%s` reads a *sequence* of character values from the input stream until it sees  whitespace or EOF and stores them to an *array* of `char` as a 0-terminated string.

Answer (score 1):

> *I'm curious about why it doesn't work when I use %c while %s works?*

Well, guess what, it did not work, even if it appeared to.

As mentioned in the man page, for `scanf()`, the type of arguments are

- `%c` expects a pointer to `char`
- `%s` expects a pointer to the initial element of an `char` array.

Quoting `C11`, chapter §7.21.6.2, (*emphasis mine*)

> `c` Matches a sequence of characters of exactly the number specified by the field
>   width **(1 if no field width is present in the directive)**.
>
> If no `l` length modifier is present, the corresponding argument shall be a
>   pointer to the initial element of a character array large enough to accept the
>   sequence. No null character is added.
>
> `s`    Matches a sequence of non-white-space characters.
>
> If no `l` length modifier is present,the corresponding argument shall be a
>   **pointer to the initial element of a character array large enough to accept the
>   sequence and a terminating null character, which will be added automatically.**

In your case,

- providing `%s` is wrong, as a single `char` is one element too short to scan and hold an array, that is null-terminated. This causes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) as memory overrun happens.
- `%c` should have *"worked"* , if the input stream did not have the `newline` stored from previous <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key press. If you clean off the input stream of all pending inputs, you'll see it works. Use something like

  ```
  scanf(" %c", &b);   //the whitespace "eats up" all the previous whitespaces
  ```

  You can see [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29658742/2173917) of mine, for details on the same.

Comment: "pointer to a `char` array" is misleading, as `%s` still expects a pointer to `char`, not a pointer to array of `char`.  The man page on my system says, "pointer to the initial element of a character array"

Comment: @Dmitri Took my time to add the related quotes, hope this is no more misleading. Thanks. :)

Comment: @SouravGhosh Thank you for your explanation. This helped me to solve my problem.