# Why are my if/else statements not working?

Tags: c, user-input

I'm starting to write code for a small bank account program, but my if/else statements aren't working. At the top of the loop, I use `scanf` to get user input about which option needs to be executed next. The first one always works, but after that, the error statements always get printed.

For example, the user types `1`. What gets printed is:

```
case 1
ERROR, please try again
```

Only case 1 should be printing, why is the Error message printing too? I tried using `switch case` statements but that didn't work either.

---

**Here's my code:**

```
char num = '7';
while (1) {
    if(num == '7') {  
        printf("0. Exit\n1. Deposit\n2. Withdrawal\n3. Add account\n");
        printf("4. Remove account\n5. Balance inquiry\n6. View accounts\n");
        printf("Enter option: (0/1/2/3/4/5/6)\n");
        scanf("%c", &num);
    }
    else if (num == '0') {
        exit(0);
    }
    else if (num == '1') {
        printf("case 1\n");
        num = '7';
    }
    else if (num == '2') {
        printf("case 2\n");
        num = '7';
    }
    else if (num == '3') {
        printf("case 3\n");
        num = '7';
    }
    else if (num == '4') {
        printf("case 4\n");
        num = '7';
    }
    else if (num == '5') {
        printf("case 5\n");
        num = '7';
    }
    else if (num == '6') {
        printf("case 6\n");
        num = '7';
    }
    else {
        printf("ERROR, please try again\n");
        num = '7';
    } 
}
```

Comment: When the user enters "1" they ultimately enter two characters: `'1'` and newline character `'\n'`. The latter is generated by `Enter` key. Your "ERROR" message is the reaction to that `'\n'`.

Comment: [related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29658685/2173917)?

Comment: You also never bother to check if `scanf()` actually reads a character.  That will cause all kinds of problems for more complex code.

Comment: Please don't post code with line numbers.

Comment: @AnT - yes you got it very correct.
kelp99 - Also, Please use switch case when you have a long ladder of if else if. Like in this case.

Answer (score 5):

The `%c` format specifier to `scanf` accepts **any** single character, including a space or newline.

If for example the user inputs "1", they are actually sending the character "1" *and* a newline character.  The "1" character is read of the first iteration of the loop and the newline stays in the input buffer.  On the next iteration, `scanf` immediately reads the newline in the buffer.  And because the character code for a newline doesn't match any of your `if` cases, it falls through to the `else`.

Change the `scanf` call to add a leading space.  That will consume any whitespace:

```
scanf(" %c", &num);
```